# Foursquare users/self/checkins API Deprecated

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm building an application that uses the Foursquare API and I'm trying to get a list of recent checkins for the authenticated user. Other parts of the API are working just fine, but when I make a get request for the below URL, it returns a deprecation error message followed by a bunch of results that seem to ignore the `afterTimestamp` param.

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?afterTimestamp=1358127640&v=20130113`

The error message:

`Please provide an API version to avoid future errors.See http://bit.ly/vywCav`

The same exact URL works perfectly fine when I use it via [their API explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore).

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The deprecation error is actually happening on all requests, even though I'm including the "v" paramater that they mention in [the link](http://bit.ly/vywCav).

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is malformed. The first occurrence of & should be replaced with a ?.

Comment: That's actually a typo on my part when I pasted it in. The actual URL being sent is using a ?.

Comment: Strange. I tried the URL you provided with my own oauth token, and didn't receive any deprecation errors? Is it possible your version parameter is malformed in some other way? Try entering the request as written into your browser, or use CURL.

Comment: I'm using the OAuth2 ruby gem to make the call. Maybe when I make the request, it's doing something improperly. I'll try to look at the raw network request and see.